# IBM Worklight: Direct Update

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I have used an Android device (Samsung Galaxy S3 Android version 4.1.1) to view the App Info of my hybrid app. The "Application" size is around 10MB and the "Data" size is around 1MB. After that, I clicked "Clear data" button so that the "Data" size became 0MB and "Application" size remained the same.
When I launch the app again, the direct update box comes out although there is no new app release (No second build has been done). Is it an expected behavior?
Worklight version: 5.0.6

Steps:

1. Deploy an app to Worklight Server and install it in the device

2. Update the HTML file and make a build

3. At this moment, the device shows the direct update dialog. Update the app to latest version.

4. Click "Clear data" in App Info

5. Launch the app again. It shows the direct update dialog again although there is no second build occurs after "Clear data" was done

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your edit with the steps you have taken, yes, this is expected.

When installing an application on a device a chucksum is generated for it in both the client and server. After triggering a Direct Update this checksum value changes and remembered. After clearing the data, you basically return the application to its previous checksum and thus when the app is re-launched (or brought to the foreground from the background), the server detects that the value in the server differs from that in the client, and sends a Direct Update request.